# Redirect to external site in Angular 5

Tags: angular, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to an external site in my Angular 5 app running locally. I'm using the following code to try and do the redirect:-

window.location.href = "www.google.co.uk";

However, when I do this, it simply appends the above onto the current localhost base url which is http://localhost:4200

eg. Redirect => http://localhost:4200/www.google.co.uk instead of www.google.co.uk

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a `base` element in your html head? can you show the full code?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>ARP Portal</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Thats my index.html. There is a base href in there pointing to "/"

Comment: Try `window.location.href="http://www.google.com"`

Comment: That worked. I also figured out what the issue was with my original url I was trying to use. It was prefixed "http//" instead of "http://" so that was why the redirect never worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the `http://` or `https://` prefix before the external link. In your case `http://www.google.co.uk` should do it.

Comment: That worked. I also figured out what the issue was with my original url I was trying to use. It was prefixed "http//" instead of "http://" so that was why the redirect never worked!